# cefsharp DownloadUrlAsync skips Cookie

Tags: c#, cefsharp, cefsharp.offscreen

load url in browser control that require cookie and authentiacaion is ok

```
  CefSharp.OffScreen.ChromiumWebBrowser browser = new CefSharp.OffScreen.ChromiumWebBrowser(Url, requestContext: reqContext);
```

but using download url

```
            var ppp =await browser.GetMainFrame().DownloadUrlAsync(Url);
            var ooop= Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ppp);
```

redirect to login page and cookie header not sent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is expected at the moment. It might be possible to add support for sending cookies.

Try adding the `UrlRequestFlags.AllowStoredCredentials` flag to the request in `DownloadUrlAsync`

A new optional param has been added to allow passing in `UrlRequestFlags` in version 116.0.150.

[Source](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/discussions/4578)